# How to get desktop-read to ignore/modify frame size?

Tags: frames, desktop

I'm using `(desktop-save-mode 1)` to save a session which I then reload, but logging in remotely from a different machine with a different resolution display.  Something stored in the desktop winds up setting frame width (but oddly, not height) to the old frame width in pixels, making the frame twice as big as it should be.  I'd like to measure the restored frame in mm or some other unit so that frames will be consistent across displays.  I'm happy to write emacs lisp to get the job done, and it looks like something might be possible using "frameset filters," but I'm lost in the weeds.

How can I get `desktop-read` to restore my frames to their intended size, even if those frames were saved on a display with different resolution?

Comment: Not sure if people who know enough are following this: you might be better served by filing it as a bug-report (for which I think it clearly qualifies).